# How to Multiprocessing pool with pymongo in python 2.7

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, python-requests, pymongo

I'm working with Pymongo and Multiprocessing Pool to run 10 processes and get data from API and insert the output into mongodb.

I think I've done something wrong the way I wrote my code, as python shows double connections open than usually it would; for example: If I run 10 processes Mongodb will output 20 or more connections been established and I will get the following warning on startup:

> UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with connect=False, or create client after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing>

Even tho I did input connect=False at the connector client in mongodb.
here's an example code to understand how I use pymongo and requests API to send the requests in pool:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

import json # to decode and encode json
import requests # web POST and GET requests. 
from pymongo import MongoClient # the mongo driver / connector
from bson import ObjectId # to generate bson object for MongoDB
from multiprocessing import Pool # for the multithreading

# Create the mongoDB Database object, declare collections
client = MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017,192.168.0.2:27017./?replicaSet=rs0', maxPoolSize=20, connect=False)
index = client.database.index
users = client.database.users

def get_user(userid):

    params = {"userid":userid}
    r = requests.get("https://exampleapi.com/getUser",params=params)
    j = json.loads(r.content)
    return j

def process(index_line):

    user = get_user(index_line["userid"])
    if(user):
        users.insert(user)

def main():

    # limit to 100,000 lines of data each loop
    limited = 100
    # skip number of lines for the loop (getting updated)
    skipped = 0
    while True:
        # get cursor with data from index collection
        cursor = index.find({},no_cursor_timeout=True).skip(skipped).limit(limited)
        # prepare the pool with threads
        p = Pool(10)
        # start multiprocessing the pool with the dataset
        p.map(process, cursor)
        # after pool finished, kill it with fire
        p.close()
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
        # after finishing the 100k lines, go for another round, inifnite.
        skipped = skipped + limited
        print "[-] Skipping %s " % skipped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there any issue in the algorithm of my code? is there any way to make it more efficient and to work better and have better control over my pool?

I've been researching quite a while but couldn't find a way to do what I want to do in a better way, would love to get some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is advised to create a `MongoClient` once for each process and not share the same client for each process.

This is because `MongoClient` also handles multiple connections from a process using connection pooling and *isn't fork-safe*.

First, you want to ensure that the while loop breaks when every document in the collection to be processed has been exhausted. Although, this is not all too granular a condition, you can break out the loop if `skipped` is greater than the count of documents.

Second, initialize the process `Pool` once outside of the loop and map processes within the loop. 
`multiprocessing.Pool.map` waits until child processes complete and return so joining the pool will result in an exception. You may consider using `multiprocessing.Pool.async_map` if you'll like to run child processes asynchronously.

You can implement this explicitly in a better way with a `multiprocessing.Queue`, producer and consumer processes. Producer processes will add tasks to the queue to be executed by consumer processes.
The benefits of implementing the solution this way are not so clear as the multiprocessing library makes use of queues as well.

```
import requests # web POST and GET requests. 
from pymongo import MongoClient # the mongo driver / connector
from bson import ObjectId # to generate bson object for MongoDB
from multiprocessing import Pool # for the multithreading


def get_user(userid):
    params = {"userid": userid}
    rv = requests.get("https://exampleapi.com/getUser", params=params)
    json = rv.json()
    return json['content']


def create_connect():
    return MongoClient(
       'mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017,192.168.0.2:27017/?replicaSet=rs0', maxPoolSize=20
    )

def consumer(index_line):
    client = create_connect()
    users = client.database.users

    user = get_user(index_line["_id"])
    if user:
        users.insert(user)

def main():

    # limit to 100,000 lines of data each loop
    limited = 100
    # skip number of lines for the loop (getting updated)
    skipped = 0
    client = create_connect()
    index = client.database.index
    pool = Pool(10)

    count = index.count()

    while True:

        if skipped > count:
            break

        cursor = index.find({}).skip(skipped).limit(limited)

        pool.map(consumer, cursor)

        skipped = skipped + limited
        print("[-] Skipping {}".format(skipped))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! definitely helped a lot!